# Как запустить метод класса-издателя через класс-подписчика?

Tags: c#, события, делегаты

Есть классы MyClass (publisher of event) с двумя полями и MyClassNotifier (subscriber of event), следящий за изменением одного из поля MyClass и при некотором условии, обрабатывающий событие. Всё это реализовано через паттерн Factory Method. Я вроде все реализовал, но не понял как вызвать само событие (метод в классе для его запуска не прописан). В условии задания сказано, что  экземпляр класса-издателя должен запуститься через метод класс-подписчика (такое вообще бывает?) и уже тогда вызывать события, на которые уже придут handler'ы. Как такое реализовать? Нужно ли прописывать еще один event для этого?

Вот отрывок из задания, где говорится, что нужно запустить метод класса (он еще не прописан в UML) через метод класса-подписчика:

> After  (MyClass) class has been created it should be called to Run. In
> response to Run, the (MyClass) fires the (MyClassEvent) event. The
> event should contain the information about the (MyClass) name and the
> fieldToChange.

[image: Упрощенная UML-диграмма кода]

Comment: Лучше не юзать `event`, используйте паттерн Observer

Comment: Вызов публичного метода - разве не решение?

Comment: @Kalmankantaja это почему же еще? `event` - просто модификатор доступа к любому делегату, не больше, не меньше.

Comment: @aepot нужен контекст кода который использует Publisher-subscriber, если у приложения несколько потребителей и им требуется какая-то информация сильно отличающаяся от исходного приложения, то нет смысла использовать этот паттерн. Конечно я понимаю, что вопрос является просто учебным заданием, но всё же. Конечно и у обсервера тоже есть свои минусы

Comment: @Kalmankantaja Я всё прописал и все было бы куда легче, если бы метод Run() находился в классе-издателе, но согласно заданию, он находится в в классе notifier'а. Вообще впервые (и надеюсь, единожды) вижу такое. У меня есть файл тестов для этого задания и там действительно запуск осуществляется подписчиком

Comment: @DartRevan это так не работает, приложите полную UML диаграмму

Comment: @Kalmankantaja просто у уже приложенной UML-диаграммы у класса MyClass есть метод Start(), который и триггерит событие fieldChanged. Но нюанс в том, что он должен запускаться через метод Run() класса MyClassNotifier